# When is the CheckResources() function called?

Tags: unity, shaders, image-effects

This question is asked in the context of image effect shader implementations in Unity.

Looking through the scripts for image effects in the standard assets package, I notice that initialization is generally done in the CheckResource() function.

The following is a snippet of code from the `BloomAndFlares` image effect.

```
public override bool CheckResources()
{
    CheckSupport(false);

    screenBlend = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(screenBlendShader, screenBlend);
    lensFlareMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(lensFlareShader, lensFlareMaterial);
    vignetteMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(vignetteShader, vignetteMaterial);
    separableBlurMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(separableBlurShader, separableBlurMaterial);
    addBrightStuffBlendOneOneMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(addBrightStuffOneOneShader, addBrightStuffBlendOneOneMaterial);
    hollywoodFlaresMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(hollywoodFlaresShader, hollywoodFlaresMaterial);
    brightPassFilterMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(brightPassFilterShader, brightPassFilterMaterial);

    if (!isSupported)
        ReportAutoDisable();
    return isSupported;
}
```

I am probably wrong in assuming that this is essentially the `Start()` or `Awake()` functions for `PoseEffectsBase`, but I decided to try implementing something simillar.

```
public override bool CheckResources()
{
    saturationPassMat = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial(saturationPassFilter, saturationPassMat);

    if (!isSupported)
        ReportAutoDisable();
    return isSupported;
}
```

Unlike the standard asset scripts, `CheckResources()` does not seem to be called consistently for me. Unity console throws `UnassignedReferenceExceptions` every frame, for the object `saturationPassMat`.

When is the `CheckResources()` function called? Should it be used for initialization just like `Start()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the PostEffectsBase class, and saw this.

```
protected void Start()
{
    CheckResources();
}
```

So... Yeah.

<s>Kinda feel like an idiot now</s>